# If a convert an object A to object B, does B keep the ArrayList from A?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Here's my code:

```
if (cards.get(i) instanceof ExtensionCard) {
    ExtensionCard d = (ExtensionCard)cards.get(i);
}
```

Here I'm creating a new `ExtensionCard` and he is getting the ArrayList that `cards.get(i)` has, and the code works just fine in that part.

In another class, I'm doing this:

```
if (this.getCards().get(i) instanceof ExtensionCard) {
    ExtensionCard d = (ExtensionCard)this.getCards().get(i);
}
```

Which is almost the same but `d` is not getting the ArrayList that `this.getCards().get(i)` has.

I need help on why is this happening.

Comment: How are you declaring `cards`? What data (other than `ExtensionCard`s) do you expect it to contain? Could you declare it as `List<ExtensionCard>` to get rid of the type casting and `instanceof` checks?

Comment: getCards() is an ArrayList<Card> and Card is extended to ExtensionCard and DeviceCard, so it can be one of them, that's why I put instanceof

Comment: OK, now what do you mean by "`d` is not getting the `ArrayList ` that `this.getCards().get(i)` has"?

Comment: My problem is that this.getCards().get(i) is getting a Card that is supposed to be an ExtensionCard with its respective array, so when I reference it to d, it would have his array. In the first part that I wrote up works fine, but in the second part the array is empty, but I added up things there before

Answer (score 2):

*Here I'm creating a new ExtensionCard and he is getting the ArrayList*

Incorrect.

You are **not** creating a new `ExtensionCard`. You are assigning the *reference* of `cards.get(i)` to a variable of type `ExtensionCard`. Both `d` and `cards.get(i)` refer to the *same* object.

*but d is not getting the ArrayList that this.getCards().get(i) has*

Since they refer to the *same* object, `d` will have a list if `this.getCards().get(i)` has a list.

Comment: What does "`d` will have a list if `this.getCards().get(i)` has a list" mean? `d` is an `ExtensionCard`. Frankly, I don't see how this answers the question (which itself is unclear).

Comment: @Mick *"d will have a list if this.getCards().get(i) has a list"* means they will have the same attributes because they are the same exact instance of an object. They are identical in literally every way, so what OP is claiming can not in fact be true.